# Reporting Services - Left to Right Mailing Labels similar scenario

Tags: reporting-services

I'm developing a report to print tagging labels (similar to mailing labels).

I've managed to make it multi-column (3 columns per row, 7 rows per page) and everything, but when I print like 5 labels, instead of getting the first row filled, and 2 columns of the second row, i get 5 rows of the first column...

How can i make the report print Left-to-Right and then top-bottom, instead of this current behaviour?

Comment: How did you managed to make it multi columns? Left-to-Right and top-Bottom is the default display of the report, you should manage to do that in the query you use to display the data.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal i used the "Columns" property on the report... i used this tutorial: http://blogs.wrox.com/article/creating-mailing-labels-in-sql-server-reporting-services/